# Twilio SIP Domain not allowing inbound calls

Tags: twilio

I have purchased an US Phone Number on Twilio and associated it with a TwiML Bin.
[image]

The content of the TwiML Bin is supposed to redirect call to my SIP Domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Welcome. Your call will be routed to an agent now</Say>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>sip:+13365518647@branko.sip.us1.twilio.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

I have created a SIP Domain Credential
[image]

I have created a SIP Domain, added the Credential and enabled SIP Registration. Upon incoming call a welcome message should be played.
[image]
[image]

When I make a phone call to the purchased phone number the welcome message is played and the call gets redirected to my SIP Domain, but the default welcome voice does not get played. Instead, in the console I get `The user you tried to dial is not registered with the corresponding SIP Domain` error. I can't figure out what I configured wrong. Shouldn't user registration occur automatically? If not, how do I register the user? Please advise

EDIT: I'm using Zoiper as softphone Client. Using Twilio SIP Domain to make outbound calls
[image]

Comment: Where is your SIP phone configuration?

Comment: @Alan , I updated the question with Zoiper config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you have wrong here is that when your TwiML bin dials your SIP endpoint, the webhook on the SIP domain will **NOT** be called. The SIP domain VoiceUrl will be called when you *originate* a call from the softphone that you have registered with the domain.

You've noticed that the console reports that your endpoint is not registered. Your softphone is responsible for registering itself and your username with the domain when it comes online.

I believe the issue you are having here is that you must specify the edge location in your softphone's domain configuration. Make sure you read the [documentation on SIP registration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-registration).

Note that the bottom of that documentation has links to download a variety of step-by-step guides on configuring various softphones. I have actually tried to use Zoiper Desktop in the same way you are, but I found that it was not sufficiently compatible -- after successfully registering, it would continually re-register itself with the domain until it hit a rate limit, and then calls would fail. I've been very happy with [Bria Solo](https://www.counterpath.com/bria-solo/) as a reliable alternative.